What does "so much as" here mean?
https://www.patheos.com/library/christianity/ritual-worship-devotion-symbolism/rites-and-ceremonies says

The most important Christian rituals are called sacraments, sacred
rites that convey God's sacred power or grace. Baptism and Eucharist
are the two most important sacraments, and are practiced by most
Christians. In many Protestant communities, these two rites are not
called sacraments, but ordinances, and are usually understood not to
be channels of grace so much as acts of commemoration and symbolic
identification with Christ.

What does "so much as" here mean?
I found that it could be replaced with "even", but that is not grammatical, lacking a conjunction.

The construction is "not A so much as B" (or "not so much A as B").

You can replace "so much as" there with "but rather" -- though the author is hedging a little when saying "so much as".  To paraphrase so much as in this not X so much as Y construction colloquially:

They're more like acts of commemoration.

In many Protestant communities, these two rites are not called sacraments, but ordinances, and are usually understood not to be channels of grace -- they're more like acts of commemoration and symbolic identification with Christ.
The sacramental is mystical and metaphysical whereas acts of commemoration are ceremonial without the mysticism, more or less.
P.S. You're looking at the wrong meaning of "so much as", where it means "hardly, even":  "The children crept into the kitchen in their stocking feet and fixed themselves a midnight snack without so much as a peep."

Thanks. What is the opposite of sacramental rites? ceremonial rites?

To use the phrase you asked about, it's not that they are opposites so much as that they are like beer and non-alcholic beer.

These notes build on the excellent answer from @TimR.
The theological setting is that Christian groups of all types carry out the same set of important rituals, such as worship, prayer, baptism, communion and so on. But the meaning and significance of these rituals varies in different church settings. As a Christian myself, this is how I would define the words sacrament and ordinance used in the OP.

An ordinance is something "ordained" for the church to do. It is the list of things that a healthy church would do regularly. It includes communion and baptism, but also the preaching of the gospel and regular times of gathered worship and fellowship.

A sacrament is a ritual which "symbolises" an important part of the gospel. Thus baptism symbolises the initial commitment to Jesus and the church, and communion symbolises the continuing fellowship between God and the church.


(Of course, these ideas have been written about and debated extensively over the centuries, so this is a very short overview.)
Now, from the perspective of the OP, the important points are:

Sacrament and Ordinance are not necessarily opposites. Think of them more as different perspectives on the same subject. If we call a birthday cake an ordinance we are saying that every birthday party should have one. If we call it a sacrament we are saying that the birthday cake rituals point to a deeper reality about the cycles of life. Personally I see baptism as both an ordinance and a sacrament of the church.

It follows from this that different streams of Christianity will have a range of opinions about the scope of both ordinances and sacraments. They will differ as to how many rituals are covered by those words. (As a comparison, what is the full list of "things that every birthday celebration should have?") They will also differ about the symbolism of the sacraments. (Again by comparison, ask many people about the meaning of a birthday cake, and you will get a range of answers.)


These two points together explain how the expression not...so much as should be understood. The writer is saying that there is a range of understanding on this whole subject. Some churches believe that the sacraments mean ABC; other churches think the sacraments mean not ABC so much as XYZ. The one point of disagreement I have with TimR's answer is that I don't read this as a hedging comment. I think it's a neutral acknowledgement that there is a wide range of understandings, and they can also overlap. So ABC and XYZ are not black and white opposites, but a range with shades of emphasis.
One simple example: All Christians understand that communion is both ordinance (we do it because Jesus Christ commanded it) and sacrament (it is a profound picture of spiritual life). But precisely because it is a picture of spiritual life, it has had a deep and open ended significance for Christians down through the centuries. The OP points to just one example. The words from the Bible are "This is my body; do this to remember me." Catholics will read that as "This really is my body", hence they see the bread as literally becoming the spiritual body of Jesus at the moment of eating. Baptists will read it as "This represents my body"; therefore it is a memorial which has value, but is no more than that. For a Catholic, God's grace can come by eating the bread; for the Baptist, grace comes through faith. But these ideas are not exclusive. Shades of these and other interpretations can be woven together in various ways. Thus "not... so much as" talks of the main emphases that the different Church groups will have.
